# An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request / Modelos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Hola hice unos cambios a esta tabla en mi base de datos y ahora estoy teniendo problemas con mi modelo de datos. Tratando de obtener mis datos obtuve el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Entiendo que el error esta en modelo de datos, ahora debo cambiarlo para que sea similar al de mi nueva tabla.
A partir de esto me han surgido una serie de preguntas con respecto a el modelo de datos. Son las siguientes:

- ¿Mi modelo debe contener el equivalente de datos que rows en mi tabla de Sql?
- ¿Puedo ocupar menos datos en mi modelo?
- ¿Cual es tipo de dato correcto para referenciar un `varbinary` en mi modelo?

Aqui dejo mi modelo de datos anterior y si me pudiesen recomendar algunos cambios para hacer esto funcionar estaría genial. Muchas gracias :D

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PCotiza_compras.Models {
  public class Requests {
    public int Id {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string Wiw {
      get;
      set;
    }


    [Display(Name = "Proyecto")]
    public string Project {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Esquema")]
    public int schemeid {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
    public string Date {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Estado")]
    public string status {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Días de expiración")]
    public int ExpirationDays {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Comentarios")]
    public string Comments {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
    public int DepartmentId {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Categoría")]
    public int CategoryId {
      get;
      set;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Intenta cambiando `modelItem => item.Status` por `modelItem=>modelItem.status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues intentaré contestar alguna de esas preguntas:

- En la vista tienes `item.Status` pero la propiedad del modelo es
  `status` con minúscula. El lenguaje C# es sensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas y puede que por eso no lo esté encontrando.
- Con respecto al tipo de la propiedad `status`, está declarado como `string` en el modelo, pero es `int` en la base de datos. O bien la declaras como `int` en ambos sitios, o bien te creas un `enum`.
- El tipo `varbinary` en C# es `byte[]`. Mira [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959269/2516718).
- En general no es necesario poner en el modelo todos los datos que figuran en la tabla de la base de datos. Puedes poner solo los que vas a necesitar.